# Node.Js partial data

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I want to have some default data accessible in all views in my Node.Js application. My data need to be in **/views/layout/header.ejs**

```
└── views
   ├── index.ejs
   └── layout
       ├── footer.ejs
       └── header.ejs
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with ejs, but usually template engines have extend and include options

Comment: I'm using include option, but it works without data selected from DB

Comment: @CrazyPenguin I'm assuming you're using express js. If you're not, my answer won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following middleware to your main file.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
      res.locals.user = req.user  //say you need loggedin user in all your views
      next();
});
```

In ejs you can use `user` anywhere, for example:

```
<%= user.userName %>
```

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry about that. It's just that some people won't upvote a helpful answer. But you were not one of them :) Have nice stay on SO!